# excel formula for finding a text string from a range and return all matching column header

Tags: excel

I have below table in excel.
[EXCEL TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aP5rM.jpg)

I want to return multiple names for whom the text is "AVAILABLE".

Do suggest your answers!!

Thanks

Comment: What formulas have you tried?  What excel are you using?

Comment: Please read how to properly ask a question in this forum.

Answer (score 0):

You could use vlookup to search "available" in each column then iserror to choose between getting column header or nothing. If you need all names in one cell you can then use concatenate.